# Exception: Can't find variable: document

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, expo

I am trying to open my app with expo on my phone and I get an error "Exception: Can't find variable: document" and if I try to open my app with expo but via the web the application works perfectly !!
Could someone explain to me what my problem is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using `window.document` in web app.

Unfortunately, both `window` and `document` are part of the web standard, not JavaScript (ECMA standard).

React Native uses JS to control rendering, but lack of DOM-manipuling itself, so you can not use many web-based APIs directly in React Native.

My suggesstion:

- Using WebView in React Native app to load your web app
- Try controling the React Native component yourself, rewrite logic

Answer (score 0):

Some features of the frame-work are only available on the web. Check through your code for things that wouldn't make sense on a mobile, like the DOM structure.